How to check a checkbox with HTML when database values are 1 or 0?
How to check a checkbox with HTML when database values are 1 or 0? I can only do this with HTML as it is a closed system that doesn't allow much or any modification.
I've tried these four below but of course, none of them worked.
<input type="checkbox" value="1" /> checked
<input type="checkbox" value="0" /> unchecked
<input type="checkbox" checked="1" /> checked
<input type="checkbox" checked="0" /> unchecked

how do you retrieve data from a database? Are you using server side code to generate the HTML?

Sounds like your database field requires an integer, but the HTML checkbox value attribute always returns a string. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#value - do you not have access to the backend to cast the value to an integer? Do you have the ability to include some javascript alongside your HTML?

You can use this method by giving your checkbox a name or an ID. When you retrieve data for the database, use $("#myCheckbox").prop("checked", true)

How would this help the OP? Can you edit your answer and elaborate a little more on what your code snippet will do and how it will solve OP's problem?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
